# Corrupted corner on tag

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

This is an extremely minor bug, but on the latest Safari for mountain lion I see that the corner of the tag bubble is messed up. I have to zoom in quite a bit to actually see it very well, but it is there. Is this a Safari-only related problem? You can see the problem on the tag "bug" to the right of this text and the button "Answer this question" (below this post)

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a safari only thing. The tags are pure CSS so they should (and do, on my PC) scale up/down extremely gracefully. I also don't see the extremely pixelated look you get either. Oddly I'm in chrome which should be using about the same rendering engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tags are rendered with pure CSS, so weirdness here is generally a browser bug.